# testcafé: An error occurred when trying to calculate a custom Selector property

Tags: testcafe

I'm using Testcafe and I have pretty straightforward selector:

```js
const tile = Selector('[data-component="tile"]');
```

And that selector is used to create this:

```js
const titleFieldTile = tile.nth(0);
const titleFieldName = titleFieldTile.find(
  '[data-testid="tile-content"] [data-testid="ps-field-form-name"]'
);
```

This is defined outside of the test, and in the test this line causes the test to fail:

```js
await t
 .expect(titleFieldType.textContent)
 .eql('text')
```

Giving this error:

```
1) An error occurred when trying to calculate a custom Selector property "header":

      ReferenceError: _ref is not defined

      Browser: Chrome 90.0.4430.93 / macOS 10.15.7
...
  58 |    await t
  59 |      // .expect(titleFieldType.textContent)
  60 |      // .eql('text')
  61 |      .expect(titleFieldName.textContent)

> 62 |      .eql('TITLE')
```

If I `console.log` the `titleFieldName` that works, it is the camparison that is causing problems, but I can't figure out why.
I have no custom DOM or methods added to the selector, so I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

Just to be clear, I've created these types of Selectors a lot, and never had a problem.

I've narrowed it down a bit.  The `.textContent` is causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work around this doing this:

```js
await t
  .expect(titleFieldType.withText('text').exists)
  .ok()
  .expect(titleFieldName.withText('TITLE').exists)
  .ok()
```

Basically filtered for the text (can be a regular expression) and then checked if anything actually matched.
It does what I need.